# SAX Parser: Specify DTD location in applet

Tags: java, xml, sax, dtd, japplet

I have an applet that works fine in the applet viewer but once deplayed to the server it can't parse the XML files

the reason is simple: the SAX parser is trying to open the dtd on the hard disk and not in the JAR.

I was told to do this:

> URLs to resources can easily be formed
>   using the URL(baseURL, pathString)
>   constructor where the base URL is
>   obtained from Applet.getDocumentBase()
>   or Applet.getCodeBase().

but I don't know how to apply this in my case:

heres a XML sample :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "leveldtd.dtd">   
<level>
...
</level>
```

and here is the init of my parser

```
public static void parseThis(InputSource is) throws Exception{
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLHandlerLevel myExampleHandler = new XMLHandlerLevel();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);
        /* Begin parsing */ 
        xr.parse(is);
    }
```

any ideas ?

Jason

Comment: It's probably just a typo and it's unrelated to your question, but your XML sample has a "note" doctype (`<!DOCTYPE note`) and the root element is `level`.

Comment: what is the problem with that ? (my xml is something completly customized that I use to stored my game levels, the dont respect a particular norm, the dtd is just to make sure the data is correctly formed)

Comment: The name in the doctype must match the root element otherwise it's invalid. I'm not sure how you can validate your XML against your DTD and not get errors.This is from "http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd":

`Validity constraint: Root Element Type` - 

`The Name in the document type declaration MUST match the element type of the root element.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If validation is not required you could just turn it of in the [SAXParserFactory.setValidating()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html#setValidating%28boolean%29) so the parser won't try to read the DTDs.

If you however do need validation you can redirect any DTD/XSD requests by setting your own [EntityResolver](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html) on the sax parser.

Comment: its an option I'm contemplating, since all the xml are correctly formed I would prefer finding out how to set the validation ^^